# Get an Error "Expected spy <functionName> to have been called" in angular 6 jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a method "onEdit" in a component. In that method I've called service method "getAttributeById", I am doing a api call in "getAttributeById" service method and return an observable and I am writing a unit test case for it but I ma getting an error

> " Expected spy getAttributeById to have been called."

```
onEdit(row) {
    if (this.role != 'Admin' && this.role != 'Owner') {
      return;
    }
    this.loadingData = true;
    this._service.getAttributeById(row['id']).subscribe((data) => {
      this.editing = true;
      this.newAttribute = { ...data };
      data.isEdit = true;

      this.loadingData = false;
      this._service.setData({attribute: this.newAttribute});
      this.router.navigate(['attributes-edit']);
    })   }
```

spec file

```
describe('MetaDataComponent', () => {
  let component: MetaDataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MetaDataComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const metaDataServiceStub = {
      getVariables: query1 => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) }),
      getAttributeById: arg1 => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) }),
      setData: object1 => ({}),
      deleteAttribute: arg1 => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) })
    };
    const routerStub = { navigate: array1 => ({}) };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [MetaDataComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: MetaDataService, useValue: metaDataServiceStub },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }
      ]
    });
    spyOn(MetaDataComponent.prototype, 'getAttributes');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MetaDataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
it('onEdit', () => {
      const payload = {id: '11111'};
      const metaDataServiceStub: MetaDataService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MetaDataService);
      const editSpy = spyOn(metaDataServiceStub, 'getAttributeById').and.returnValue(of({}));
      expect(component.onEdit(payload)).toBeUndefined();
      expect(editSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I am getting below error

```
Expected spy getAttributeById to have been called.
Error: Expected spy getAttributeById to have been called.
    at stack (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/U1192079/Projects/r2d2-ui/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2455:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/U1192079/Projects/r2d2-ui/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:2425:14)
    at Spec.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/U1192079/Projects/r2d2-ui/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:901:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/U1192079/Projects/r2d2-ui/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?0b1eaf7a13cae32191eadea482cfc96ae41fc22b:524:34)
    at Ex
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this testing framework but I notice the line

const editSpy = spyOn(metaDataServiceStub, 'getAttributeById').and.returnValue(of({}));

I don't know if the part ".and.refurnValue" is part of the matching. If it is, I think for the method getAttributeById to be considered "called" you say it should return an empty object.... Which I think it will never do because you've set it up to return an object that contains a subscribe() method when called.

Comment: We can do like this also because I didn't write any expectation for the response of the subscribe(), I am just checking whether it have been called or not ?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to change: "const editSpy = spyOn(metaDataServiceStub, 'getAttributeById').and.returnValue(of({}));" into "const editSpy = spyOn(metaDataServiceStub, 'getAttributeById');" and does that fix your test?

Comment: Few other things to check: 1) you have 2 variables containing the mock service. Do they point to the exact same object instance? 2) there is an if statement before the method you're checking for (checking some roles). Are you absolutely sure your method is called?

Comment: ... and 3) double-check your facts. you've tried a few things already that you said didn't work. Are you sure they're not working for the exact same reason? (Or did it fix your problem but then you bumped into the next big in your code, and seeing a failed test made you assume it was for the same reason?)

Comment: Yes Dennis, You take me to correct direction, your second point is true, 
there is an if statement which is not allowing to execute code inside it. Thanks buddy. I am up voting your answer but not marking it as answer,